# Multiple Correspondence Analysis with None-Binary Categorical Dummy Variables in Python using mca and prince modules

Tags: python, pandas, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I am using a [python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mca/1.0) for multiple correspondence analysis on multiple categorical variable. I am studying a set geological data, here is a sample preview:

```
    Quartz  Oxides  Hematite    Limonite    Geothite    Clay    Soil_Type   
       1      2       3            4            1        0         A
       2      1       4            3            0        1         B
       3      4       2            1            4        0         A
       4      3       1            2            0        3         C
       0      2       3            4            1        2         D
       1      0       2            4            3        4         C
```

0 - not present, 1 - present in very small (trace) amounts, 2 - present in small amount, 3 - present in medium amount, 4- present in abundant amounts.

my code is as follow:

```
geology = pd.read_csv('geology_data.csv')
x = geology[['RigNumber','Quartz','Oxides','Hematite','Limonite','Geothite','Clay']].fillna(0)
y = geology[['Soil_Type']]
print 'Dimensionality Reduction'
mca_ben = mca.mca(x)
print mca_ben
mca_ind = mca.mca(x, benzecri=False)
print mca_ind
print(mca.MCA.__doc__)
```

However I am receiving an error stating:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\root\Desktop\Data\raw data\new raw\merged wit npt\multiclass without productive\parameter propagation\New Predict\clustering-mca.py", line 33, in <module>
    mca_ben = mca.mca(x, ncols=31)
  File "C:\Users\root\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\mca.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.D_r = numpy.diag(1/numpy.sqrt(self.r))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\twodim_base.py", line 302, in diag
    res = zeros((n, n), v.dtype)
MemoryError
```

I am suspecting that mca is only limited to dichotomous dummy variables.

I also tried to transform each dummy variable into separate columns by using

```
x = pd.get_dummies(x)
```

but to no avail, I am still getting the same error.

Note that I do not want to use [PCA because of obvious reasons.](https://www.quora.com/Can-one-use-dimension-reduction-algorithms-like-PCA-for-categorical-variables)

I also used another python package called [prince](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/prince) and I tried the example found in the [documentation](http://prince.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), unfortunately I am also receiving an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\root\Desktop\Data\raw data\new raw\merged wit npt\multiclass without productive\parameter propagation\New Predict\clustering-mca.py", line 14, in <module>
    mca = prince.MCA(df, n_components=-1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prince\mca.py", line 42, in __init__
    super(MCA, self).__init__(
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the first, but the second error is likely because prince is a python3-only package which doesn't support python 2.

Answer (score 2):

I am using python 3 and the mca-library. You should create an indicator matrix and perform the MCA on that matrix, the class `mca` has a dummy function:

```
dummy(DF, cols=None)
```

then you can use it as:

```
x_dummy = mca.dummy(x)
mca_ben = mca.mca(x_dummy)
```